# How do I fix this vertex pattern?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, vertices

[image: ![Arm_mesh]

I accidentally deleted a few vertices on this mesh and tried to fix this by manually creating a new "web" of faces where they were missing. As you can see it ends up looking kinda crooked and the shading get's messed up on the mesh since it's no longer accurately following the pattern. Is there a better way to fix this than having to grab each one of the vertices and try to drag them into the right position until they align with the others?

Comment: you could retopo over it, its a lot of manual work...

Comment: I would try to select a range of vertices surrounding the bump and use the loop tools add-on to relax the mesh to see if that helps.

Comment: maybe duplicate it, shrinkwrap with the copy as Target, and rotate the mesh with Proportional Editing on, so that the mesh is now straight (if this is your goal)? But you could share your file so that we give a try: https://pasteall.org/blend/